# Create two y axis with different ticks in ui.Chart.image.series in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using ui.Chart.image.series to make one time-series chart about vh, ndvi,lswi,evi. **But vh is negative and much larger than Other indices**. I want to put them in one chart, and set different ticks for vh and index. But the chart is too crowded for index.
Any better way?

```
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
          imageCollection: s1merges2,
          region: f, 
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
          scale: 100
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: id.getInfo(),
          lineWidth: 0.5,
          pointSize: 1,
         vAxes: {
                0: {
                    title: "vh" ,
                    baseline: 0 ,
                    titleTextStyle: { bold: true , color: 'blue' } ,
                    viewWindow: { min: -30 ,max: 0, 'ticks': [-30, -22.5, -15, -7.5, 0]}
                  } ,
                1: {
                    title: "index" ,
                    baseline: 0  ,
                    titleTextStyle: { bold: true, color: 'green' } ,
                    viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 1, 'ticks': [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]}
                  }
         }
//       'vAxes': [
//   {'title': 'NDVI', 'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'ticks': [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]}},
//   {'title': 'VH', 'viewWindow': {'min': -30, 'max': 0, 'ticks': [-30, -22.5, -15, -7.5, 0]}}
// ]

        })
```

[image]